Is falsifiability a wrong standard for deciding if a theory is "scientific"?
This question stems from a comment by @Conifold:

"Falsifiability" is a wrong standard that is no longer used (if it ever was) because any theory can be "saved" by suitable auxiliary "adjustments". Hence the references to what the best theories assert or will assert. But the causal closure of the physical is testable. For example, if our best theories interpret observations as, say, the outcome of quantum collapse being influenced by the 'mind' without detecting any physical substrate of such influence (as Penrose et al. suggest) then causal closure will be rejected.

First, I am not sure how one can call a philosophical standard “wrong” when all of these standards are debated in the philosophical literature unless that is merely one’s opinion. Secondly, an ad hoc modification of a theory is now a different theory. For example, the hypothesis “all swans are red” may be falsified by the existence of a white swan. If one then modifies the hypothesis and rephrases it as “all swans are red except this one”, then the hypothesis now becomes different.
So, is there actually any philosophical consensus on falsifiability being a “wrong” standard for deciding if a theory is scientific?

Falsifiability isn't a "standard for judging theories", it's a part of a demarcation for what counts as "science".  If your theory isn't falsifiable, then it's generally not considered within the purview of science, which tests theories through reproducible empirical observations.  Basically, if one can't possibly conceive of observable tests for a theory, then maybe you can still judge the theory, just not with the scientific method.

@Him well, one can still judge the merits of a theory by how falsifiable it is, so I don’t think that’s accurate. Nevertheless, the linked comment is pointing to criticisms of falsifiability as a demarcation of science anyways, and I’m not sure if there is any consensus on it being a wrong standard even for that purpose

@Him I agree with you. If you believe that falsifiability is a spectrum of values rather than a binary choice then you could apply some kind of standard. But falsifiability does not determine the truth, just the ability of empirical evidence to refute.

@IdiosyncraticSoul again, the question is not just about whether or not it's a wrong standard for determining truth, but also whether or not it's a wrong standard for demarcating between science and non science. The comment linked in the question is referring to the latter.

@syed: I have rewritten the headline on the question to try to reflect that distinction and reduce the risk of misinterpretation. Feel free to revert, or to edit further.

@keshlam sounds good, the edit makes sense

Note that falsifiability in philosophy would be related to proving that the process of deriving the conclusion was incorrect, rather than whether the conclusion is accurate or not. Science has to meet the additional requirement of adequately modeling the real world, preferably more successfully than previous theories, at least within a defined range of conditions.

@keshlam by the way, after some thought, I decided to revert it but not exactly, since my question was more about whether or not it is now understood by most philosophers that falsifiability is a wrong standard, not whether or not falsifiability is a standard for demarcation in general, to which the answer obviously seems yes

I don't know how you would get the answer to what most philosophers now believe short of doing a survey, or at least an intensive literature search to make sure you have found most philosophers and their answers. Might make an interesting paper...

@keshlam I mean I agree, that’s why I was confused when the linked comment said it’s a wrong standard. Wrong standard based on who?

Falsifiability seems to be out of fashion as far as the received opinion is concerned.  It is probably true that it is deficient as a criterion.  However, I think there are reasonable grounds to think that it still may be useful as a standard (or a necessary condition).


the outcome of quantum collapse being influenced by the 'mind' without detecting any physical substrate of such influence == Woh Syed, when did Penrose say this? Is this more solipsism magic? You don't have to explain it, just give a link.


@MissUnderstands that quote is from Conifold, not me. Not sure what he’s referring to

"Secondly, an ad hoc modification of a theory is now a different theory." No more than adding a spoiler to your car makes it a new car.

You quote a comment saying:

"Falsifiability" is a wrong standard that is no longer used (if it ever was) because any theory can be "saved" by suitable auxiliary "adjustments".

In "The Logic of Scientific Discovery", Sections 19 and 20 Popper explains this objection and proposes a solution. Any auxiliary hypothesis that tries to get around a refutation should be rejected unless it is independently testable.
Here's an example illustrating Popper's idea. In 2011 the OPERA collaboration said they had made observations that seemed to imply neutrinos were moving faster than light. If the observation was correct then a lot of current physics would be wrong. They were wrong. In reality they had made a mistake in setting up the experiment by incorrectly connecting a fibre optic cable delaying a signal carrying time information from a GPS receiver. This theory about the fibre optic cable could be tested by a variety of means like plugging the cable in properly, or introducing a similar defect in another way such as deliberately introducing the delay in another way like testing the effect of plugging in cables wrongly in a simpler experiment elsewhere. If the OPERA collaboration had tried to fix the problem by saying neutrinos only travel faster than light in their experiment, that would have been rejected out of hand.

Falsifiability is still being used by the people who understood it correctly, but not by those who misunderstood it.
The latter wrongly believe that faslfiability implies that scientists go around trying to disprove themselves all the time. They understand the criteria as a description of scientific activity. But Popper was NOT speaking of science as a praxis. He was looking for a criterion able to distinguish science from other things, that may improperly pretend to a scientific status.
Basically, the criterion says: an idea that won't submit to the verdict of facts cannot pretend to be scientific. And that still stand.

Suppose theory T predicts or logically entails that reality should look like R under conditions C. Suppose we manage to recreate conditions C and observe what reality looks like under those conditions. Instead of R, we observe S. What can we conclude from this?

Option 1: T is wrong. How wrong? That would depend on whether the mistake lies in a core tenet of the theory, in which case a major revision would be needed, or in a minor aspect of the theory, in which case only a minor revision would suffice.
Option 2: T is correct, but R does not actually follow from T under conditions C (perhaps we misinterpreted the theory, made a logical mistake in our inference, had the wrong expectations, etc.).
Option 3: T is correct, but we failed to perfectly recreate conditions C. In this case, it would not be surprising that we did not observe R.

Of course, there could be combinations of these options—for instance, the theory T might be wrong, our logical derivation of expectations might be flawed, and our recreation of conditions C might also be imperfect.
Falsification of T would only truly occur under Option 1, which would require first ruling out Options 2 and 3. Even under Option 1, as Conifold pointed out, T could be revised and adjusted to fit the data. If only minor details need adjustment, it might be more accurate to say that minor elements of the theory were falsified, rather than claiming that the entire theory was falsified. However, if core tenets of the theory are proven incorrect, it would be fair to say that the whole theory was falsified, necessitating the development of an entirely new theory.
In short, this analysis by cases—guided by simple common sense—shows that falsifiability can lead to productive and nuanced revisions of a theory, its implications, and the practical steps involved in testing it.
When would falsifiability be inapplicable (i.e., when would a theory be unfalsifiable)?

If T makes no predictions R about reality.
If T does predict R, but R is unobservable (i.e., we would not be able to empirically observe R, even if it did occur somewhere in a domain we cannot observe).
If the conditions C are too vague, or if they are clear but practically impossible to recreate with accuracy.

Why would we want a theory to be falsifiable?
If a theory is not falsifiable, it means we cannot inspect reality to see if it matches the theory. There would be no way to compare the two. The theory would become useless: if it is false, we would have no way of knowing; if it is true, we would have no way of knowing either. The truth or falsehood of the theory would be indistinguishable, leaving us in complete uncertainity. The theory would fail to provide practical insights about reality or actionable predictions that could be observed and tested empirically. It would, in effect, offer nothing of value and remain indistinguishable from fiction.
Why would falsifiability be a "wrong" standard?
I see nothing wrong with falsifiability under the nuanced view I've outlined here, which is grounded entirely in common sense. The core intuition behind falsifiability is to compare theories against reality and check whether they align—and that makes a ton of sense.

We often have a mistaken understanding of falsification. Falsification, as Popper postulated it, is primarily intended for empirical researchers who lack the option to engage with complex philosophy. It is important that you can prove your ideas, but this is not only possible through empirical methods; you can also provide proof through pure reason (as Kant demonstrated). If you take a closer look at Schopenhauer, you will gain a deeper understanding of real falsification within a broader philosophical system. There are different types of falsification, not just the simple one proposed by Popper.
